# CSS - flex grid layout

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I have a simple grid using flex.

I need three columns and a margin in between each block but not on the last block of each row.

This is working here but I also need all the blocks to be 100% of the container so I dont want the margin after the 3rd block.

Is it possible to have a grid like this where the blocks are a percentage and the margin on the inside and not against the container.

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 900px;
  justify-content: flex-start;

}

.block__item {
  background: grey;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 2px);
  margin-right:2px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you avoid "discovering hot water". This is a lightweight, simple and intuitive grid system, check it out [flexboxgrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 900px;
  justify-content: flex-start;

}

.block__item {
  background: grey;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.block__item:last-of-type {
  border-right: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `last-child`/`nth-child` to remove margin from the last element of each row  and rely on `flex-basis`/`flex-grow` to set the width:

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 900px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin:10px 0;

}

.block__item {
  background: grey;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  flex-basis:26%; /*Smaller than 33% and bigger than 25%*/
  flex-grow:1;
}
.block__item:not(:last-child):not(:nth-child(3n+3)) { 
  margin-right:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
</div>

<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
  <div class="block__item"></div>
</div>
```